# Linear Algebra - Clarifying the meaning of a lemma related to linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am reading through Jim Hefferon's ["Linear Algebra"](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/) and have encountered a lemma which I have had some difficulty in understanding. Through reading various other resources, I believe I currently understand the lemma but I am not complete sure. I would appreciate it if someone could confirm or correct my understanding.

The lemma is located near the end of Chapter 3, Section II.1 and reads as follows:

> For vector spaces V and W, the set of linear functions from V to W is itself a vector space, a subspace of the space of all functions from V to W.

What I believe this means is that there is a set of linear functions, $G = \{G_1, G_2, ...G_n\}$ that map $V$ to $W$ such that these maps conform to the rules of vector spaces. As an example for all $G_k, G_m \in G,$ we would have closure: $G_k+G_m \in G,$ associativity under addition: $G_k+G_m = G_m+G_k$, additive identity: $G_k + G_n = G_k, G_n \in G$, etc.

Further, I believe the portion of lemma that reads:

> "... subspace of the space of all functions from V to W."

states that there are some non-linear functions that map from $V$ to $W$ and that the functions we would include in $G$ (as defined in the previous paragraph) would be the subset of of these functions which are linear.

Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: You are basically correct. When you say "there is a set of linear functions", though, the book says "all the linear functions taken together" form a vector space.

Comment: Looks good to me. Just keep in mind that $G$ must be ALL the linear functions from $V$ to $W$, and that $G$ isn't necessarily finite, perhaps not even countable.

Comment: One thing to note: you write $G = $ some finite set, but the set of linear functions $V\to W$ is in general not finite. It is finite only if the spaces are finite-dimensional and the common field of the vector spaces is finite. This is *not* the case with the typical examples $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R^n$, for example, or even when the field is the rationals $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You may want to check that the set is indeed a vector space just to convince yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The set of linear functions is a subset of the set of all functions. Suppose V and W are the real line. A linear map would be just multiplying by a scalar. However, sending a number to its square is not linear.